# раскраска setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы текст мерцал разными цветами. Но он в итоге просто синий. Не понимаю, пробовал уже по разному. Всё равно не выходит. setTimout должен запускать функцию с задержкой. В итоге текст просто синий. Как верно прописать это в коде?   Спасибо!

```
$(document).on('ready', function (){
    var link = $('.flashing');
    function painting() {
            link.css("color", "yellow");
    };

    function painting2() {
            link.css("color", "red");
    };

    function painting3() {
            link.css("color", "blue");
    };
    setInterval(function(){
        painting();
        setTimeout(painting2(), 700);
        setTimeout(painting3(), 1400);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: _setTimeout_ первым параметром принимает функцию. У тебя же классическая ошибка: вызов функции вместо передачи

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем коде

```
setTimeout(painting2(), 700);
```

эквивалентно

```
painting2();
setTimeout(undefined, 700);
```

Вот как надо (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```js
var link = $("span");

function painting() {
  link.css("color", "yellow");
};

function painting2() {
  link.css("color", "red");
};

function painting3() {
  link.css("color", "blue");
};

setInterval(function(){
  painting();
  setTimeout(painting2, 700); // not painting2()
  setTimeout(painting3, 1400); // not painting3()
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Two roads diverged in yellow wood ...</span>
```

Comment: каждое второе срабатывание таймаутов будет совпадать

Comment: @Grundy я знаю, тем не менее, три цвета отчетливо видны

Comment: стоит дописать пояснения в ответ, о том что было не так и почему

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю конкретно Вашу ситуацию, но правильнее сделать это с помощью `css` -

```css
.сhristmas {
  animation: сhristmas 1s linear 0ms infinite;
}

@keyframes сhristmas {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  40% {
    color: green;
  }
  100% {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="сhristmas">Happy New Year</span>
```